# Get all rows in table A even if no rows in table B in CROSS JOIN

Tags: sql-server

I Have This query

```
SELECT *
FROM ( ( SELECT SUM(Auditoria.Importe - ISNULL(Auditoria.Pago, 0)) AS Deuda
         FROM Auditoria 
           INNER JOIN
              Articulos_Auditoria ON Auditoria.CUD = Articulos_Auditoria.CUD 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
              Cancelaciones ON Auditoria.CUD = Cancelaciones.CUD
         WHERE (Cancelaciones.CUD IS NULL) 
           AND ( CAST(Auditoria.Fecha AS date) <= CAST(@Fecha AS date) ) 
           AND (Auditoria.Terminal = @Term) 
           AND (Auditoria.Id_Empresa = @empresa)
           AND (Articulos_Auditoria.Cortado = 0)
        ) AS Deuda      
     CROSS JOIN 
       ( SELECT DISTINCT Pagos_Auditoria.TipoPago, 
                         SUM(Pagos_Auditoria.Cantidad) AS Cant
         FROM Pagos_Auditoria 
           INNER JOIN
              Auditoria ON Pagos_Auditoria.CUD = Auditoria.CUD 
           INNER JOIN
              Articulos_Auditoria ON Auditoria.CUD = Articulos_Auditoria.CUD
         WHERE ( ( ( CAST([Fecha] as date) ) <= CAST(@Fecha as date) ) 
             AND (Auditoria.Terminal = @Term) 
             AND (Articulos_Auditoria.Cortado = 0) 
             AND (Auditoria.Id_Empresa = @empresa)
               )
         GROUP BY Pagos_Auditoria.TipoPago
       ) AS Pagos
     )
```

Table A is `Deudas` an table B is `Pagos`. It works fine when rows in Table B (`Pagos`) are returned, but I want to see rows in table A and get 0 in fields of table B if no rows are
returned from Table B.

**Specifications**
 - Table A `Deudas` have always rows to return
 - Table B `Pagos` *may* have rows to return
 - There's no ID or Key between the tables

I tried a sub `SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXIST` but for the quantity of 
evaluated rows is not very efficient.

What is the simplest way to do it?

**Edit 1**

I tried

```
SELECT *
FROM ((SELECT        SUM(Auditoria.Importe - ISNULL(Auditoria.Pago, 0)) AS Deuda
FROM            Auditoria INNER JOIN
                            Articulos_Auditoria ON Auditoria.CUD = Articulos_Auditoria.CUD LEFT OUTER JOIN
                            Cancelaciones ON Auditoria.CUD = Cancelaciones.CUD
WHERE        (Cancelaciones.CUD IS NULL) AND (CAST(Auditoria.Fecha AS date) <= CAST(@Fecha AS date)) AND (Auditoria.Terminal = @Term) AND (Auditoria.Id_Empresa = @empresa) AND (Articulos_Auditoria.Cortado = 0)) AS Deuda

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT DISTINCT Pagos_Auditoria.TipoPago, SUM(Pagos_Auditoria.Cantidad) AS Cant
FROM            Pagos_Auditoria INNER JOIN
        Auditoria ON Pagos_Auditoria.CUD = Auditoria.CUD INNER JOIN
        Articulos_Auditoria ON Auditoria.CUD = Articulos_Auditoria.CUD
WHERE (((CAST([Fecha] as date))<=CAST(@Fecha as date)) AND (Auditoria.Terminal = @Term) AND (Articulos_Auditoria.Cortado = 0) AND (Auditoria.Id_Empresa = @empresa))
GROUP BY Pagos_Auditoria.TipoPago) AS Pagos ON TRUE)
```

but I get

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

I'm missing something?

Comment: That's a left outer join.

Comment: @KennethFisher for left outer join a key or relation is needed between tables, but in this case there's any

Comment: Ahh in that case do a FULL JOIN with a WHERE clause to check for NULL in the left table.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN ... ON TRUE`

Comment: @KennethFisher and how and where do I have to put the check for NULL values, can you explain? Table B is where I should check for no Rows returned

Comment: You put a WHERE clause at the end to exclude NULLs in one of the Table A columns so that you don't get Table B rows where there was no match on Table A.  @ypercube's answer is probably easier however.

Comment: @ypercube I tried you solution, and get an exception, I added the full description in Edit 1

Comment: What DBMS are you suing? SQL-Server? Try `1=1` instead of `true`.

Comment: I've reformatted your 1st bit. I did not remove the tens of redundant parentheses. I wonder how you can read queries with that format

Comment: I think the `DISTINCT` can/should be removed as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an `outer apply` instead of a `cross join`.

Using this simplified table structure.

```
create table T1(ID1 int);
create table T2(ID2 int);
```

Add three rows to `T1`

```
insert into T1 values(1);
insert into T1 values(2);
insert into T1 values(3);
```

Query with `outer apply`.

```
select T1.ID1,
       T2.ID2
from T1
  outer apply (
              select T2.ID2
              from T2
              ) as T2;
```

Result:

```
ID1         ID2
----------- -----------
1           NULL
2           NULL
3           NULL
```

Add one row to `T2`

```
insert into T2 values(1);
```

Result:

```
ID1         ID2
----------- -----------
1           1
2           1
3           1
```